# UIScrollview's don't keep their level

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have 2 `UIScrollview`s next to each other.
They are hooked up together on their vertical-value. (up and down)

As it turned out as I drew some sort of graphic across both views (actually in each of the views... but the graphic (a line) goes visually across). At some point when you
pan wildly around and start accelerating and decelerating it, the scrollviews don't keep level.
When stopping this, they level up again (in some sort of animation), but I actually want them to stick together no matter what the user does.

I played around a lot, but I am running out of ideas, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 0):

so it works if you're panning slowly?
i think it depends on how you hook uiscrollviews together... i mean you're passing vertical values from one to the other one but not the acceleration isn't it? post some code please

Comment: hi mate,I answered you above!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it works slowly. it works even sweet if I pan very quickly, but it breaks if i do a lot of stopping and accelerating and stuff.

basically I created my uiscrollview in my viewcontroller and hooked them up in IB.
i am using the scrollviewdidScroll-delegate-method to keep them synchronised. i tried it with KVO as well, but no difference. the funny thing is, I have a scrollview on top of the content-scrollview too. I have never managed to get them(contentscroll and columnscroll) out of sync, no matter what I am doing.

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
  if (scrollView.dragging || scrollView.tracking) 
  {

  ```
  if (rowScrollView == scrollView) 
  {
      [contentScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(contentScrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
  } 
  else if (columnScrollView == scrollView) 
  {
      [contentScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, contentScrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
  }
  else if (contentScrollView == scrollView)
  {
      [columnScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0) animated:NO];
      [rowScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
  }
  ```

  }

thank you

Tom